# Dynamically Bind Gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, aspxgridview

****Second values of text boxes adding and deleting the first values in gridview...****

### **Code**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gender", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qualification", typeof(System.String)));

            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr["Age"] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr["Gender"] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr["Qualification"] = TextBox4.Text;

            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);


            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(System.String)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gender", typeof(System.String)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qualification", typeof(System.String)));

            DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
            dr1["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr1["Age"] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr1["Gender"] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr1["Qualification"] = TextBox4.Text;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            ds1.Tables.Add(dt);


            GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because you are writing it to happen.
If you want to add new records in grid view, then before adding new ones you should preserve existing ones.

In your case you are adding first set of record like this

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gender", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qualification", typeof(System.String)));

            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr["Age"] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr["Gender"] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr["Qualification"] = TextBox4.Text;

            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);


            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Which is fine, you are making some data and binding it to grid view.
And when you are trying to bind new data, you are doing the same kind of thing again which is

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(System.String)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gender", typeof(System.String)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qualification", typeof(System.String)));

                DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
                dr1["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
                dr1["Age"] = TextBox2.Text;
                dr1["Gender"] = TextBox3.Text;
                dr1["Qualification"] = TextBox4.Text;

                dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

                DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                ds1.Tables.Add(dt);


                GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataBind();
```

Which actually is replacing your data source for grid view, I think better option would be using some kind viewstate storage to store table values and bind them again with grid view.

Try to do it this way-

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Gender", typeof(System.String)));
            dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qualification", typeof(System.String)));

            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr["Age"] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr["Gender"] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr["Qualification"] = TextBox4.Text;

            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
```

after this add new record here in same table

```
  DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
            dr1["Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
            dr1["Age"] = TextBox2.Text;
            dr1["Gender"] = TextBox3.Text;
            dr1["Qualification"] = TextBox4.Text;

            dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);

            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            ds1.Tables.Add(dt1);


            GridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

This will work for you.
If you are adding data dynamically then you should use ViewState to store ds temporarily.

Comment: No its also not working when i add new datarow in dt

Comment: please check my edited answer... it should work now :D